# Privilege Level Required to Install and Maintain Sharepoint 2013

Tags: installation, access

I am not a Sharepoint expert by any means, and really have zero experience with it.  I am however one of our network administrators and domain administrators.  The question has come up of how high of a privilege level an account needs to be to install and maintain a Sharepoint installation on servers that are already attached to our domain.  I have been told domain admin level, however that seems to me odd and I would not like to have any individuals with that level of access outside of our network admin team.  Can anyone provide a quick rundown of the access level required to install and maintain Sharepoint 2013 (and maybe 2010)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the Domain Admin rights to install and Configure the SharePoint. But the account under which you install the SharePoint should be Local Admin on server. If farm admin account is separate than the Install account then that account should be in local admin.

Read the below blog for detail information about the services accounts and their permissions.

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html